# iPhone: counting unique items in an array

Tags: iphone, arrays, count, unique

Groan.  I have spent hours trying to count the number of unique items in a sorted array.  Basically I have A,B,B,B,B,C,C,D,E,M,X,X.  All I need to know is the that there is 1 A, 4 Bs, 2 Cs etc.  Help appreciated.